# OpenCV: findContours exception

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

my matlab code is:

```
h = fspecial('average', filterSize);
imageData = imfilter(imageData, h, 'replicate');
bwImg = im2bw(imageData, grayThresh);

cDist=regionprops(bwImg, 'Area');
cDist=[cDist.Area];
```

opencv code is:

```
cv::blur(dst, dst,cv::Size(filterSize,filterSize));
dst = im2bw(dst, grayThresh);

cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours(dst,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

here is my image2blackand white function

```
cv::Mat AutomaticMacbethDetection::im2bw(cv::Mat src, double grayThresh)
{
    cv::Mat dst;
    cv::threshold(src, dst, grayThresh, 1, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
    return dst; 
}
```

I'm getting an exception in **findContours()**  C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000003F6E09E0A0.

Can you please explain what am I doing wrong.
dst is cv::Mat and I used it all along it has my original values.

Update here is my matrix written into *.txt file:
http://www.filedropper.com/gili

UPDATE 2:
I have added `dst.convertTo(dst,CV_8U);` like Micka suggested, I no longer have an exception. however values are nothing like expected.

Comment: Have you tried with other images?  Does it happen with any image you put in, or only a particular image?  What I mean to say is that is this error reproducible?  Please put up the image that you're using, as well as all of the code required to produce `dst`.

Comment: Is your input image 8UC1 (single channel 1 byte)?

Comment: @Micka my matrix is black and white image - 0 and 1, I have uploaded my file

Comment: @rayryeng Please have a look in here to see - if i'm doing the threshold wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this question which has a similar problem to what you're encountering: [Matlab and OpenCV calculate different image moment m00 for the same image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894375/matlab-and-opencv-calculate-different-image-moment-m00-for-the-same-image).

Basically, the OP in the linked post is trying to find the zeroth image moment for both `x` and `y` of all closed contours - which is actually just the area, by using `findContours` in OpenCV and `regionprops` in MATLAB.  In MATLAB, that can be accessed by the `Area` property from `regionprops`, and judging from your MATLAB code, you wish to find the same quantity.

From the post, there is most certainly a difference between how OpenCV and MATLAB finds contours in an image.  This boils down to the way both platforms consider what is a "connected pixel".  OpenCV only uses a four-pixel neighbourhood while MATLAB uses an eight-pixel neighbourhood.

As such, there is nothing wrong with your implementation, and converting to `8UC1` is good.  However, the areas (and ultimately the total number of connected components and contours themselves) between both contours found with MATLAB and OpenCV are not the same.  The only way for you to get exactly the same result is if you manually draw the contours found by `findContours` on a black image, and using the `cv::moments` function directly on this image.

However, because of the differing implementations of `cv::blur()` in comparison to `fspecial` with an averaging mask that is even, you still may not be able to get the same results along the **borders** of the image.  If there are no important contours around the borders of your image, then hopefully this will give you the right result.

---

Good luck!

Comment: you wrote I need to find the contours manually ? not using findcontours?

Comment: No no.  Yes you can use `findContours`, but take those results and use the pixel locations to draw them on to a blank image.  So use `drawContours`.